# Function thinks I am passing in a float

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute the distance between all pairs of coordinates in two arrays.  Here is some code I have written:

```
def haversine(x,y):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    print(type(x))
    lat1, lon1 = np.radians(x)
    lat2, lon2 = np.radians(y)

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

haversine = np.vectorize(haversine)
```

The arrays are `gas_coords` and `postal_coords`.  Note that

```
type(postal_coords)
>>>numpy.ndarray

type(gas_coords)
>>>numpy.ndarray
```

and that each of these arrays have two columns.

When I try to compute the distance `using scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` I get the following error:

```
in haversine(x, y)
      6     # convert decimal degrees to radians
      7     print(type(x))
---->; 8     lat1,lon1 =np.radians(x)
      9     lat2,lon2 = np.radians(y)
     10 

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

`haversine` seems to think the input `x` is a float rather than an array. Even when I pass arrays into `haversine` like `haversine(np.zeros(2),np.zeros(2))` the same issue arises.  I should note that this only happens after vectorization through `np.vectorize`.

From looking at `haversine`, the arguments are not altered in any way.  What could be causing the error?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

gas_coords = np.array([[50, 80], [50, 81]])
postal_coords = np.array([[51, 80], [51, 81]])


cdist(postal_coords, gas_coords, metric = haversine)


>>>array([[ 111.19492664,  131.7804742 ],
          [ 131.7804742 ,  111.19492664]])
```

Comment: `np.radians` gives one numpy array as the output not two.

Comment: How do you call haversine? Could you please show the input to the function with a minimal working example?

Comment: @today `a,b = np.zeros(2)` returns a = 0 and b = 0.  That part of the code is fine, I think it is a problem with the vectorization.

Comment: @Scotty1- see my edit

Comment: Obviously `x` is passed to `haversine` as a scalar, since vectorize vectorizes `haversine` by iterating over the elements in the input arrays.Thus radian returns only a single float instead of an array. today is right with what he said. Btw.: Which output do you want to have for the coordinates given?

Comment: `np.vectorize` passes scalars to your base function.

Comment: @Scotty1- Oh, I see where the error is then.  Ok thank you.  I've included an desired output for the minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the desired outputs, the error can be avoided by not vectorizing the `haversine` function, since this passes scalars to the function (as stated in the comments above). So you can just call `cdist` with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def haversine(x, y):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    print(type(x))
    lat1, lon1 = np.radians(x)
    lat2, lon2 = np.radians(y)

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

gas_coords = np.array([[50, 80], [50, 81]])
postal_coords = np.array([[51, 80], [51, 81]])

cdist(postal_coords, gas_coords, metric=haversine)
```